# Check the value of an Observable<boolean>

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

Using Angular 9 I have an `Observable<boolean>`.

I need to check the value in the Observable. Should I do this?

```
if (observableOfBoolean.pipe(map((x: boolean) => x)))
  return true;
```

How should I check a condition with the value in an Observable?

Comment: You probably want to return the observable itself and subscribe to it in wherever you need to use that `true` value.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as an observable is involved, the entire data flow that depends on it becomes asynchronous. So you need to either subscribe to or use `value` getter if it's of type `BehaviorSubject`. It cannot be used synchronously.

```js
someFunction() {
  observableOfBoolean.subscribe(
    data => {
      if (data) {
        // value in observable is true
        // you cannot do `return true` here
      } else {
        // value in observable is false
      }
    }
  );
}
```